# parallel matrix multiplication using PBLAS

Tags: parallel-processing

I have searched a lot of websites and resources but couldn't find any C or FORTRAN code example of parallel matrix multiplication using PBLAS PDGEMM function, could you please help me to find such resources.

Thank you in advance.

I have got an example of pblas.tar.gz from netlib website, did the make and executed it on Linux cluster using mpi but the program is executing the same run on all nodes without splitting the matrices.

Answer (score 0):

A classic case would be the ScaLAPACK software and associated examples, such as http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/examples/example1.f

In case you misunderstood, PDGEMM will not "split the matrices", it expects the input data to already be distributed properly (i.e., 2D block-cyclic distribution).