# matrix multiplication in fortran using mpi and mkl

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-mkl

The problem I am having is mainly related to MPI. I have developed the code to multiply two matrices using mpi and mkl in fortran. It is giving the correct output but the issue is that if I increase the numberof processors for the calculation then the time taken to calcualte gets increase as well, i.e. it takes 36 seconds to multiply matrices using 4 processors but it takes 58 seconds for 5 processors. And I have come to know that processor with rank 1 takes more time than others inspit of the weight is almost same for all the processors. i.e. if NP=4 then rank=1 takes same amount of time([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ3NQ.png)), others are taking but for NP=5, rank=1 is taking more time than others([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LXzu.png)).

```
use mkl_service
include 'mpif.h'

! variables

!------mpi initialization---!

!----someoperation---!

    if(rank.eq.root)then

!       some task then
        
        do i=1,nworkers-1
            call mpi_send(nobsvld, 1, mpi_int, i, 3, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
        end do

! multiplication routine called

        call matrixMultiply(dble(p), dble(htra), phtra, nsea, nsea, nobsvld, nworkers, mpi_comm_world, rank, mpi_int, mpi_real8)
        
        call matrixMultiply(dble(hvld), phtra, hphtra, nobsvld, nsea, nobsvld, nworkers, mpi_comm_world, rank, mpi_int, mpi_real8)

!       some task then

        call matrixMultiply(gmm, inovvld, gain, nobsvld, nobsvld, 1, nworkers, mpi_comm_world, rank, mpi_int, mpi_real8)
    
        call matrixMultiply(phtra, gain, gainres, nsea, nobsvld, 1, nworkers, mpi_comm_world, rank, mpi_int, mpi_real8)

        !       some task then
    else
!---Worker---!

        call mpi_recv(nobsvld, 1, mpi_int, 0, 3, mpi_comm_world, stats, ierr)
        call recv_cal_send(nsea, nsea, nobsvld, mpi_comm_world, mpi_int, mpi_real8,rank)    
            
        call recv_cal_send(nobsvld, nsea, nobsvld, mpi_comm_world, mpi_int, mpi_real8,rank) 
        
        call recv_cal_send(nobsvld, nobsvld, 1, mpi_comm_world, mpi_int, mpi_real8,rank)    
    
        call recv_cal_send(nsea, nobsvld, 1, mpi_comm_world, mpi_int, mpi_real8,rank)   

    end if

    call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program

!-------------------------------------routines-----------------------------------!

!-------------------routine for root to send as well as calculate some of the portion and receive from workers--------------------!
subroutine matrixMultiply(A, B, C, ax, ay, by, n, comm, rank, dt_int, dt_real)
    integer :: ax, ay, by, rows, averows, extra, e_row, offset, source, ierr
    integer, dimension(5) :: stats  !mpi_status_size==5
    real*8 :: A(ax,ay), B(ay,by), C(ax,by)
    real*8, allocatable :: A_buff(:,:), C_buff(:,:)
    
!-------------------------------------send portions to workers-------------------------------------!    
    offset=1
    averows=ax/n
    extra=modulo(ax,n)
    
    if(extra.gt.0)then
        offset=offset+averows+1
    else
        offset=offset+averows
    end if
    
    do i=1,n-1
        if(extra.gt.i)then
            rows=averows+1
        else 
            rows=averows
        end if
        
        e_row = offset+rows-1

        call mpi_send(rows, 1, dt_int, i, i, comm, ierr)
        call mpi_send(offset, 1, dt_int, i, i, comm, ierr)
        call mpi_send(B, ay*by, dt_real, i, i, comm, ierr)
!call cpu_time(s1)
        allocate(A_buff(rows,ay))
        A_buff(1:rows,1:ay)=A(offset:e_row,1:ay)
        call mpi_send(A_buff, rows*ay, dt_real, i, i, comm, ierr)
!call cpu_time(s2)
!print*,s2-s1," to send to",i
        offset=offset+rows
        deallocate(A_buff)
    end do
    
!-------------------------------------calculate the portion of itself-------------------------------------!
    if(extra.gt.0)then
        rows=averows+1
    else 
        rows=averows
    end if

    allocate(A_buff(rows, ay))
    
    A_buff(1:rows,1:ay)=A(1:rows,1:ay)
    
    allocate(C_buff(rows,by))
call cpu_time(c1)
    call dgemm('N','N', rows, by, ay, 1.d0, A_buff, rows, B, ay, 0.d0, C_buff, rows)
call cpu_time(c2)
print*,c2-c1," for calculation by root"
    deallocate(A_buff)
    
    C(1:rows,1:by)=C_buff(1:rows,1:by)
    
    deallocate(C_buff)
    
!-------------------------------------receive calculated portions from workers -------------------------------------!

    do i=1,n-1
        source=i
        call mpi_recv(rows, 1, dt_int, source, source, comm, stats, ierr)
        call mpi_recv(offset, 1, dt_int, source, source, comm, stats, ierr)
        
        e_row = offset+rows-1
        allocate(C_buff(rows,by))
        call mpi_recv(C_buff, rows*by, dt_real, source, source, comm, stats, ierr)
        
        C(offset:e_row,1:by)=C_buff(1:rows,1:by)

        deallocate(C_buff)
    end do

end subroutine

!---------routine to receive portion from root to calculate and send back----------!
subroutine recv_cal_send(ax, ay, by, comm, dt_int, dt_real,rank)
    
    integer :: comm, rank, dt_int, dt_real, ierr, offset
    integer :: source, ax, ay, bx, by, cy, rows
    integer, dimension(5) :: stats  !mpi_status_size==5
    real*8, dimension(ay,by) :: B
    real*8, allocatable :: A_buffer(:,:)
    real*8, allocatable :: buff(:,:)
    
    bx=ay
    cy=by
    source = 0

    call mpi_recv(rows, 1, dt_int, source, rank, comm, stats, ierr)
    call mpi_recv(offset, 1, dt_int, source, rank, comm, stats, ierr)
    call mpi_recv(B, bx*by, dt_real, source, rank, comm, stats, ierr)
    allocate(A_buffer(rows,ay))
    call mpi_recv(A_buffer, rows*ay, dt_real, source, rank, comm, stats, ierr)

    allocate(buff(rows,cy))
call cpu_time(c1)
    call dgemm('N','N', rows, by, bx , 1.d0, A_buffer, rows, B, bx, 0.d0, buff, rows)
call cpu_time(c2)
print*,c2-c1," for calculation by",rank
    deallocate(A_buffer)
!call cpu_time(s1)

    call mpi_send(rows, 1, dt_int, 0, rank, comm, ierr)
    call mpi_send(offset, 1, dt_int, 0, rank, comm, ierr)
    call mpi_send(buff, rows*cy,dt_real, 0, rank, comm, ierr)
!call cpu_time(s2)
!print*,s2-s1," cal sent by",rank
    deallocate(buff)
end subroutine
```

Comment: How many cores (not hyperthreads) on your system? could it be possible that ranks 0 and 4 end up time sharing the same core?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. What exact CPU model do you have?

Comment: I have intel i7 8th gen

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz

Comment: From https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/149091/intel-core-i78565u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html, your cpu has 4 cores and 8 hyperthreads.

Comment: but the same issue is arising when I run this code on HPC

Comment: What exact CPU on the HPC? How many MPI processes? What exact scaling results? Please [edit] you question with the details.

Comment: Don't write your own distributed memory matrix multiply. Use a library such as PBLAS (part of ScaLapack)

Comment: To help clarify what you are doing could you show how these two routines are called - is it some master-slave type thing? Even better would be a complete code showing us exactly what you are doing. And what size matrices are we talking about? Also please use `Implicit None`, and don't use the non-standard, never been standard real*8

Comment: Should I disable Hyperthreading?

Answer (score 2):

(Note lacking a complete example program I'm having to make a few assumptions about what is going on here - should a full example be provided I will modify as appropriate. Note also there may be an issue with the number of real cores you have in your system, but as I understand it your solution his real problems that are independent of this)

I am afraid that the way you have written this is inherently non-scalable, and it's non-scalable in two different ways; it is not scalable in time and, worse to my mind, it is not scalable in memory. The former is the cause behind the poor performance you are observing, the latter means that using more processes will not allow you to solve bigger problems.

To try and understand what I mean by the former let's try and make a little model of the time taken by the solution above when running on P processes for NxN matrices. The time taken for the compute that performs the matrix multiplication will be proportional to N**3/P , which is a nicely decreasing function of time as P increases, good. But you also have to pass messages, and in particular you seem to send all of B from rank 0 to all the other processes. The time for this will, as the code is written, be proportional to P*N**2 (ignoring latency), which is an *increasing* function of time with P - the more processes you use, the slower the communication becomes. Thus the total time is a sum of the (decreasing) compute time with the (increasing) communication time - and for sufficiently large P this will tend to infinity, *not* zero; this is what I mean by inherently non-scalable in time. Now the problem you have in your case is the compute is quite quick, so at least for the N you are using it only requires quite modest P before the communication time dominates, and the time to solution will increase approximately linearly with the number of processes.

You can marginally improve this by using `mpi_bcast` (and `mpi_gatherv` for the final result). This will change the communication time to Log(P)*N**2, but it's still increasing, and so the algorithm is still inherently non-scalable. And more generally my experience is that these master-slave algorithms are rarely worth investigating at all if you want performance - only if the compute is **ferociously** expensive do they have any worth.

The above could be helped if you increase N - this makes the compute time more expensive compared to the communication time and so you are more likely to see the decrease with P due to the former, than the increase due to the latter at least to a larger value of P; at some point the communication time will always take over. But because you hold all the matrices on all processes you can't solve any bigger a problem on P processes than you can on 1. This is what I mean by inherently non-scalable in memory.

A good solution to this will address both problems, and if you really want a good solution both issues are coupled and must both be addressed - you *must* use a properly distributed memory solution if you want good parallel scaling in time. For matrix multiplication an example algorithm is [Cannon's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon%27s_algorithm) which, in the spirit of the little model above, has compute time proportional to N**3/P and communication time to N**2/Sqrt(P) - note these are both decreasing functions of P, so the time to solution here tends to zero; this is a scalable algorithm in time. Further the memory use per processes is proportional to N**2/P, again a decreasing function of P, and so this algorithm is also scaling in memory. But you shouldn't write this yourself - a number of parallel libraries are available which implement these scalable algorithms for matrix multiplication, I use [ScaLapack](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/) (see also [parallel matrix multiplication using PBLAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476324/parallel-matrix-multiplication-using-pblas)) and MKL has a version of this library available; there are also free versions.

Edit:
A couple of other thoughts

1. You have made sure you are using single threaded BLAS calls?
2. If you are only interested in single node parallelism use a parallel BLAS call - you will get great performance for minimal investment of effort

Comment: Could you change that phrase to "master-worker" or even "manager-worker"? Otherwise you're entirely spot on.

Comment: So I have some work for master process to do, then comes multiplication then again some tasks and so on. By the way I have distributed system.

Comment: Also I have edited the post for your refference